# Primes $p$ with $\mathrm{ord}_p(z)\equiv a\pmod d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a$, $z$, and $d\ge 2$ are integer numbers such that $z$ is not a perfect power; in particular, $z\notin\{0,\pm1\}$. What can be said about the existence / infinitude of the primes $p\equiv 1\pmod d$ such that $\mathrm{ord}_p(z)\equiv a\pmod d$? Such that $\mathrm{ord}_p(z)\not\equiv a\pmod d$?

At least, do there exist / are there infinitely many primes $p\equiv1\pmod d$ with $\mathrm{ord}_p(z)$ divisible / not divisible by $d$?

I suspect that algebraic number theory can be relevant, but if possible, I would prefer to have an elementary solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $ord(z)$? How is that related to $p$?

Comment: The order of $z$ in $\mathbb F_p^\times$.

Comment: Why the restriction $p\equiv1\pmod d$?

Comment: @GregMartin: Think, for example, of $a=0$. Suppose that $p\not\equiv1\pmod d$. Are there (infinitely many) primes $p$ with $d\mid\mathrm{ord}_p(z)$ / with $d\nmid\mathrm{ord}_p(z)$? The answers to both questions are immediate. I tried to avoid such trivial situations.

Comment: About your "At least,..." question- let $p$ be any prime $\equiv1$ mod $d$. Then we have that $d$ divides $p-1$. It is known that, for any prime, $p$, there exists an element (known as a primitive root), $q$, such that $ord_p(q)=p-1$. So clearly $d\mid ord_p(q)$. So, basically, any prime congruent to $1$ mod $d$ will do the trick. There are indeed infinitely many such primes, but a proof of that is hardly elementary - it follows from [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). I hope this gives you a better scope of this problem.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22: We do not choose $z$, it is given to us. There exists some $q$ with $d\mid\mathrm{ord}_p(q)$, but this does not help us: we want   
 $d\mid\mathrm{ord}_p(z)$ to hold.

Comment: @reuns: correct, but does it help (particularly taking into account that Artin's primitive root conjecture is still open)?

Comment: @W-t-P Yes for $a=0$, but for other $a$ it doesn't seem to be a trivial situation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most elementary answer but at least it's an answer... 
Consider the sequence:
$$a_n=z^n-1$$
Zsigmondy theorem assures that (with minor exceptions) each number in this sequence has a prime divisor $p_n$ which does not divide any previous terms. That is we have:
$$z^n \equiv 1\pmod{p_n}$$
And:
$$z^k \not \equiv 1 \pmod{p_n}$$
For all $1 \le k <n$. So by definition of the order we must have:
$$ord_{p_n}(z)=n$$
So for each $n$ (again, with minor exceptions) there exist such prime that $z$ has this order modulo this prime which is much stronger than both your assertion as well as its negation. 
 
Also note that the weaker version (infinitude of primes such that $p\equiv 1\pmod d$ or $p \not \equiv1\pmod d$) follows directly from the Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progressions (which is also not quite elementary result).

Comment: This is an answer to either of the two properties separately, but the OP asked for primes with both properties simultaneously.

Comment: @GregMartin What do you mean by "both properties simultaneously"? One is about primes for which $\mathrm{ord}_p(z)\equiv a\pmod d$ and the other for which $\mathrm{ord}_p(z) \not \equiv a\pmod d$, they obviously can't happen at the same time.

Comment: By Zsigmondy's theorem, for each $n\in\{a,a+d,a+2d,\dotsc\}$ there is a prime $p$ such that $\mathrm{ord}_p(z)=n$ - but why will this $p$ satisfy $p\equiv 1\pmod d$?

Comment: It seems that your argument solves the *at least* part of the problem for $z>0$, but the general case, as well as the case $z<0$, remain open - do you agree? (Also  @GregMartin )

Answer (score 0):

$$z=dx+b\\y=dc+a\\p=de+1\\f=pg+1\\z^y=f\implies b^{dc+a}\equiv g+1\bmod d$$

if d was prime, this would lead to :$$b^{c+a}\equiv g+1\bmod d$$

In the d is composite ( and in general) case, this just replaces c with $$(d-\varphi(d))c$$

That's how far I got so far.